# what is emit function in dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have come across `emit` function when studying `dropzone` snippet.

```
    <?php
        if(isset($update) && !empty($team_marketing_photos)){
    ?>
        var team_marketings = '<?php echo json_encode($team_marketing_photos,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ?>';
        team_marketings = JSON.parse(team_marketings)
    <?php }else{
        ?>
        var team_marketings = "";
        <?php
    } ?>

    let dz1 = $(".js-marketing-dropzone").dropzone({
        ...dropzoneOptions,

        init: function () {
            if ( team_marketings != '') {
                var _this = this
                $.each(team_marketings, function(key,value){
                    var teamMarketingCounter = 'team_marketing' + key
                    if ($(_this.element).attr('id') == teamMarketingCounter) {

                        var mockFile3 = {
                            name: value.photo_name,
                            size: 12345
                        }
                        _this.emit("addedfile", mockFile3)
                        _this.emit("complete", mockFile3)
                        _this.emit("thumbnail", mockFile3, value.photo_name)

                        $(_this.element).find('input:hidden').val(value.id);
                    }
                })
            }
        },
    });
```

What does `.emit` function do? Is this some kind of triggering?

Answer (score 0):

The `emit` function allows you to preload an image in a `dropzone`.

Answer (score 0):

`emit` is a method in the Dropzone library that is used to **trigger** events. Dropzone.js internally uses emit to fire various events at different stages of the file uploading process.

Interestingly there is no explaination of `emit` method in the [Dropzone Documentation](https://docs.dropzone.dev/), but you can find the definition of it in [emitter.js](https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/6249bfc1af493aba43fe4b7198f9571b2d3d9c24/src/emitter.js).